# Category pagination shows same posts

Tags: pagination

My blog is showing same posts on every page, but this is only happening with Category Pagination (maybe with Tag Pagination too). You can't see the problem in the front page.

Front page: http://pandasnacozinha.com.br

Category page: http://pandasnacozinha.com.br/bolos-doces-e-sobremesas

The only pagination plugin I'm using is "Category pagination fix". I've already tried deactivating it, but nothing happened.

Searching around, I've tried several suggestions, however, I am not an expert when it comes to PHP so I could really use some help here.

Can you shed some light?

Thank you.

Giovanna

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This generally happens when you don't use some fixed term in the URL for category. For example, instead of:

`http://pandasnacozinha.com.br/bolos-doces-e-sobremesas`

The category link can be:

`http://pandasnacozinha.com.br/category/bolos-doces-e-sobremesas`

The setting is in `WordPress Admin` => `Settings` => `Permalinks`.

Here, either you keep `Category base` blank or write a term like `category`, `topic` etc.

However, from your source code, it looks like you placed a dot `.` in there or used a setting from **Yoast SEO** to hide the term `category` from URL. Hiding the terms like `category`, `tag` etc. are possible, but often causes problem such as this if you are not careful.

Comment: If I only knew it was that simple! I defined "categoria" for my category base and everything is working just fine now. Thank you very much for your help.