# Duplicate Category and Page URL loads Category instead of the Page

Tags: categories, permalinks, pages, slug, duplicates

I have created a Category with the slug `service`, which has the permalink: `https://example.com/service`.

and a Page with the link: `https://example.com/service`.

In the Category `service`, there is a post with the link like: `https://example.com/service/post1`

Now the link `https://example.com/service` is redirecting to the Category Archive, but I want it to load the Page instead.

How can I do that?

Comment: May I ask why? What you have done is create complexity on something that should be straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Load `Page` when a `Page` and a `Category` archive have the same URL:

***This is default WordPress behaviour***: When you have the same URL for a category archive & for a page, WordPress will load the page instead of the category archive.

> So unless you have a plugin that is changing this behavior for your WordPress setup, your duplicate URL should load the page, not the category archive.

### To achieve the proper URL Structure:

The URL structure you wanted needs some work. So unless you've done it already, follow the instructions below to achieve the said URL structure:

```
# URL structure for Pages:
https://example.com/page-slug
```

This happens by default, you don't need to do anything.

---

```
# URL structure for Categories
https://example.com/category-slug
```

For this:

1. Go to: `WordPress Admin Panel Menu` → `Settings`.
2. Put a single dot (`.`) in the `Category base` text field.
3. Click <kbd>Save Changes</kbd> button.

---

```
# URL structure for Posts
https://example.com/category-slug/post-slug
```

For this:

1. Go to: `WordPress Admin Panel Menu` → `Settings`.
2. Select `Custom Structure` and enter `/%category%/%postname%/` in the `Custom Structure` text field.
3. Click <kbd>Save Changes</kbd> button.

> If for some reason you are not getting the expected result from this, then use this URL structure in a WordPress installation with:
>
> 1. WordPress Core updated to the latest version.
> 2. No plugin is activated
> 3. A default theme like [Twentyseventeen](https://wordpress.org/themes/twentyseventeen/) is activated
>
> and then see what happens with duplicate Page and Category URL.

### Solving the Category Pagination Problem:

If you [check this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/251869/110572) you'll see that this kind of URL structure will cause some pagination problem in your category archive pages. This happens because WordPress confuses with `/page/2` part as a different page or post.

For example: say you have a category named `service` and `service` category has posts like `web development`, `hosting` etc. with the following URL:

```
https://example.com/service
https://example.com/service/web-development
https://example.com/service/hosting
```

Now you may have multiple pages in your `service` category argive page, like:

```
https://example.com/service
https://example.com/service/page/2
https://example.com/service/page/3
```

Because of this URL structure, WordPress thinks you are trying to load **a post** that has the slug `post` under the `service` category and that post is a [paginated post](https://codex.wordpress.org/wp_link_pages).

So instead of loading the next pages of your `service` category archive, WordPress will try to load a paginated post with the slug `page` and you'll get a `404` (page not found) error instead.

To fix this, you may use a simple plugin with the following CODE:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name:  Category Pagination Fix
Plugin URI:   https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/308826/110572
Description:  Fix category pagination for possible conflicts with page or post url
Version:      1.0.0
Author:       Fayaz Ahmed
Author URI:   https://www.fayazmiraz.com/
*/

function wpse308326_fix_category_pagination( $query_string = array() )
{
    if( isset( $query_string['category_name'] )
            && isset( $query_string['name'] ) && $query_string['name'] == 'page'
            && isset( $query_string['page'] ) ) {
        $paged = trim( $query_string['page'], '/' );
        if( is_numeric( $paged ) ) {
            // we are not allowing 'page' as a page or post slug 
            unset( $query_string['name'] );
            unset( $query_string['page'] )  ;

            // for a category archive, proper pagination query string  is 'paged'
            $query_string['paged'] = ( int ) $paged;
        }
    }   
    return $query_string;
}
add_filter( 'request', 'wpse308326_fix_category_pagination' );
```